# Exchange mail attachment extraction using managed code

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, managed, extract

Does anyone know of a way to copy mail attachments of a particular extention from mail when they arrive from exchange 2003, into a shared directory using managed code?

I know one way is to use vbscript, using sinks that exchange exposes. however I was wondering if anyone had seen a sample in managed code, perhaps using interop??

Any sample code greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of free/opensourse, not to mention commercial imap, and pop3 libraries that can expose the functionality you are looking for.  Personally, I would setup a delivery rule to flow said emails to a given folder, and use IMAP for the client downloader.

[IMAP on Codeplex](http://www.google.com/searchq=c%23+imap+site%3Acodeplex.com)